Optimizing TeX Live Installation for Continuous Integration: Is Installing Directly from CTAN the Best Approach?
On my local machine, I typically install the full TeX Live distribution along with a large number of fonts. As long as everything builds, I'm content.
However, the situation is different when running in a CI environment. TeX Live is too heavy for such purposes, and I've realized that the pre-built versions available on Ubuntu, Alpine, and other distributions do not include tlmgr, which offers more flexibility to manage TeX packages.
To address this, I came across a solution where I install TeX Live directly from CTAN within a Dockerfile and then selectively add only the packages I need. Here’s an example of the Dockerfile I'm using:
FROM alpine:3.20.2

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    perl \
    wget \
    curl \
    xz \
    ghostscript \
    fontconfig \
    ttf-freefont \
    py3-pygments

# Installer TeX Live
ARG TL_MIRROR="https://texlive.info/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet"

RUN mkdir "/tmp/texlive" && cd "/tmp/texlive" && \
    wget "$TL_MIRROR/install-tl-unx.tar.gz" && \
    tar xzvf ./install-tl-unx.tar.gz && \
    ( \
        echo "selected_scheme scheme-basic" && \
        echo "instopt_adjustpath 0" && \
        echo "tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0" && \
        echo "tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0" && \
        echo "TEXDIR /opt/texlive/" && \
        echo "TEXMFLOCAL /opt/texlive/texmf-local" && \
        echo "TEXMFSYSCONFIG /opt/texlive/texmf-config" && \
        echo "TEXMFSYSVAR /opt/texlive/texmf-var" && \
        echo "TEXMFHOME ~/.texmf" \
    ) > "/tmp/texlive.profile" && \
    "./install-tl-"*"/install-tl" --location "$TL_MIRROR" -profile "/tmp/texlive.profile" && \
    rm -vf "/opt/texlive/install-tl" && \
    rm -vf "/opt/texlive/install-tl.log" && \
    rm -vrf /tmp/*

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linuxmusl"

RUN tlmgr install latexmk fontspec minted babel-french adjustbox capt-of \
  csquotes datatool emptypage enumitem environ epigraph fontawesome5 gensymb \
  glossaries imakeidx listofitems minitoc stackengine tcolorbox titlesec \
  tocloft wasysym booktabs caption euenc filehook lm makecmds microtype \
  parskip ulem unicode-math lualatex-math tikzfill units pdfcol nextpage \
  hyphen-french noto notomath luatexbase

RUN apk add font-noto font-noto-music font-noto-emoji font-noto-cjk font-noto-naskh-arabic \
    font-noto-devanagari font-noto-hebrew font-noto-tamil font-noto-tibetan font-noto-math font-noto-symbols

RUN wget https://github.com/cc-icons/cc-icons/raw/master/fonts/cc-icons.otf -P /usr/share/fonts/truetype/creativecommons

RUN fc-cache -fv
RUN updmap-sys
RUN luaotfload-tool -u -v

Note that I initially used GitHub Actions such as xu-cheng/latex-action@v3, but it is heavy and the image is missing some fonts.
To summarize:

Is this an acceptable solution for setting up TeX Live in a CI environment, or is there a better approach? Specifically, I want to ensure that the setup is optimized for speed and size, without sacrificing the ability to manage packages via tlmgr.
Are there any potential pitfalls or inefficiencies in this approach? For example, am I duplicating any installations, or is there a more efficient way to manage fonts and packages in this Dockerfile?
Is there a significant difference in using this method on Alpine compared to using a distribution like Ubuntu, especially regarding package management and tlmgr?

I'm looking for best practices to optimize the Docker image for CI environments while keeping TeX Live manageable and not too bulky.
EDIT
I tried to optimize my Dockerfile by using an existing base:
FROM kjarosh/latex:2024.2-basic

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    perl \
    wget \
    curl \
    xz \
    ghostscript \
    fontconfig \
    ttf-freefont \
    py3-pygments

RUN tlmgr update --self
RUN tlmgr install latexmk fontspec minted babel-french adjustbox capt-of \
  csquotes datatool emptypage enumitem environ epigraph fontawesome5 gensymb \
  glossaries imakeidx listofitems minitoc stackengine tcolorbox titlesec \
  tocloft wasysym booktabs caption euenc filehook lm makecmds microtype \
  parskip ulem unicode-math lualatex-math tikzfill units pdfcol nextpage \
  hyphen-french noto notomath luatexbase

RUN apk add font-noto font-noto-music font-noto-emoji font-noto-cjk font-noto-naskh-arabic \
    font-noto-devanagari font-noto-hebrew font-noto-tamil font-noto-tibetan font-noto-math font-noto-symbols

RUN wget https://github.com/cc-icons/cc-icons/raw/master/fonts/cc-icons.otf -P /usr/share/fonts/truetype/creativecommons

RUN fc-cache -fv
RUN updmap-sys
RUN luaotfload-tool -u -v

But this time my build fails, but I have the exact same docker rules...
[1{/opt/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!
<./assets/c-logo.pdf>] [2]
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'page.1'
[1] (/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'page.2'
[2] [1] [2] (./course-c/00-preface/index.tex [3] [4]
(./_minted-index/trac.pygstyle)
(./_minted-index/0E7CFEE255982651A08A0480EF1BBEAB3015DB4A8D3AC963E485BDD90D0A79
7D.pygtex)
(./_minted-index/5197F6E47B56D32C5741E8A4FA0EB90D3DD8C79243393C7FE17D6C5BED85B6
08.pygtex)
! Undefined control sequence.
\environment tcb@drawing code ...UseTaggingSocket 
                                                  {tcb/drawing/begin}\Suspen...

l.56 \end{code}

This showing that LaTeX installation looks very delicate. I noticed later that if I do:
RUN tlmgr update --self

It solves the issue. It means if the docker image is cached, the behavior may differ and could lead to unexpected errors.

CI environments is rather generic and different CI systems work best with different approaches. Since you mention both: Do you specifically look for a Docker environment or for GitHub Actions? If you use GitHub Actions: Are you using a Docker container in your pipeline anyway?

Your approach is I think easiest in general. But maybe you want to stay closer to your local LaTeX installation, or use MiKTeX to install packages automatically, or cache the image to avoid possibly installing different package versions in a later build rerun. If we are purely talking about build speed, probably use your own runners.
